# Chromium doesn't play Twitch.tv-Streams/Videos

Tags: video, chromium, ffmpeg

In Ubuntu 17.04. the current version of Chromium doesn't play Twitch.tv-Streams/Videos in HTML5. There is only is a black video-window, but the video is not starting.

What i tried:

- installed package "chromium-codecs-ffmpeg"
- installed the latest dev-version of chromium include Widevine from here:
  https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-dev

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by install the package "chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra". HTML5-Streams on Twitch.tv running excellent now.